# Use intellij as the default merge tool for TortoiseHG/Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, intellij-idea, tortoisehg

I would use hg4idea to do this but it seems to leak memory badly.  Is there a way to use Intellij 9 as the default merge tool for TortoiseHG/Mercurial?  KDiff3 makes very little sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I'm afraid it's not possible. Consider using some third-party diff/merge tool. The closet one to IDEA is [SmartSynchronize](http://www.syntevo.com/smartsynchronize/index.html), also written in Java and will work on any platform.

Comment: I am curious as to any updates to this, several years later?